# Rspec expect issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a test:

```
describe "#send_email" do
  let(:sender) { create(:sender) }
  let(:email_account) { sender.email_account }

  ...
  it "refreshes oauth" do
    expect(email_account).to receive(:refresh_oauth)

    sender.send_email(email)
  end

end
```

And the code:

```
class Sender
  def send_email(email)
    ...
    email_account.refresh_oauth
   end
 end
```

The test fails with `expected 1 time, received 0 times`. I tried adding debug info to the `refresh` method to see if it fires and it does. What am I missing?

One possible thought is that `email_account` passed to `expect` and the one in the test are actually 2 separate references to one object. If so, what would be an appropriate spec?

Comment: in your `Sender` class how are you loading the `email_account` variable? Is it an ActiveRecord model and you're doing a `find` by the passed in `email` or something else? Whatever you're doing to load that object you'll need to stub it to return the one with the expectations on it

Comment: @SimpleLime well that's what I was trying to avoid, but it seems like there is no other way. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: how is your factory implemented?

Comment: @Ilya it's a regular FG factory with `email_account` relation.

Comment: If you showed us how `email_account` method looks, it would be easier to help.